# punteros inteligentes diferencia entre shared_ptr vs make_shared

Tags: c++, c++11

Sé que make_shared realiza una sola asignación de memoria dinámica mientras que shared_ptr hace dos cuando es iniciado con new, pero cuando se debería preferir uno sobre el otro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make_shared` es una función tipo utilidad que encapsula la creación de un `shared_ptr`. Es decir, `make_shared` te devuelve un `shared_ptr`.

Por otro lado, como bien has comentado, `make_shared` ofrece una pequeña mejora sobre crear el objeto `shared_ptr` a mano y es que en una única reserva de memoria se almacena el objeto referenciado y el conteo de referencias.

Con este panorama en mente, lo recomendable es usar `make_shared` siempre que sea posible, ya que reducimos la fragmentación de la memoria, dejando la creación de `shared_ptr` a mano únicamente cuando no tengamos otra opción.

¿Y cuándo se puede dar el caso de que no podamos usar `make_shared`? Es algo que nos puede pasar a usar código antiguo (no adaptado a C++11). Puede suceder que tengamos funciones que devuelvan punteros crudos y que estos punteros, en nuestro propio código, deseemos gestionarlos con punteros inteligentes. Dado que el objeto ya ha sido creado no podremos usar `make_shared`, pero en cambio sí que podremos delegar la gestión de su ciclo de vida en un `shared_ptr`.

Un ejemplo para resolver posibles dudas:

```
class Objeto
{
public:
  Objeto(int);
};

// Esta funcion devuelve un puntero. Es tu responsabilidad liberar
// la memoria cuando ya no sea necesario.
Objeto * funcion_antigua();

int main()
{
  // Siempre que podamos deberíamos crear los shared_ptr asi:
  std::shared_ptr<Objeto> objeto1 = std::make_shared<Objeto>(123);

  // Al usar interfaces antiguas podremos encapsular los punteros
  std::shared_ptr<Objeto> objeto2 { funcion_antigua() };
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WLfvqW2qp2qctHbC)

Comment: da error al compilar @eferion

Comment: el mensaje exacto de g++ es: error: conversion from 'Objeto*' to non-scalar type 'std::shared_ptr<Objeto>' requested std::shared_ptr<Objeto> objeto2 = funcion_antigua();

Comment: @theriver el único problema es que el constructor de `shared_ptr` es explícito y está así precisamente para evitar conversiones *sin querer* que provoquen errores raros... pero es un contratiempo facil de solucionar, como puedes ver.